# Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'. Remove one definition in webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am getting the error mentioned above even though I am not using DataSourceID anywhere in my code and I made sure I am not binding the data from code behind and client side.

**Markup:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
            OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
            EnableModelValidation="True">
```

**C# Code:**

```
if (ShouldWeBindToGridView == true)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

This is the full code behind as requested:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                        OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableModelValidation="True">

                        <Columns>

                            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" Visible="False" />

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID Number" SortExpression="Student_IDNumber">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID2") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID3") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID1") %>'></asp:Label> <br />
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID2") %>'></asp:Label> <br />
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID3") %>'></asp:Label> 

                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                        </Columns>
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" HorizontalAlign="Left"
                            VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt"
                            ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" HorizontalAlign="Left"
                            VerticalAlign="Top" />
 </asp:GridView>
```

**This is the C# Code:**

```
 private void Load_Grid(bool ShouldWeBindToGridView)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcnn);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Students", conn);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
            catch
            { }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        if (ds != null)
        {
            if (ShouldWeBindToGridView == true)
            {

                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();


            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I am not using DataSourceID  at all and I am binding the data just in C# Code.

**The error message:**

```
Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.ConnectToDataSourceView() +10967460
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +28
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

Comment: Please, clarify what you mean by saying "I'm not binding the data from code behind and client side"

Comment: @HarutyunImirzyan I mean I'm not using DataSourceID in my markup and DataSource  in my C# code at the same time to bind the data.

Comment: can you share full code behind code?

Comment: @HarutyunImirzyan I shared the full code as you requested.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the code behind, it's the aspx markup. Please, share the .cs file contents also

Comment: Instead of `Bind` you should use `Eval`. Which line of code gives you the error ?

Comment: @HarutyunImirzyan sorry, my bad. Please see the update.

Comment: Maybe you're setting DataSourceID in the Page_Load event?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya there is no specific error throwing an error. It is just the error message that I shared above is been displayed.

Comment: @HarutyunImirzyan I triple checked and DataSourceID does not even exist in my whole solution.

Comment: Then, please, comment out this line `GridView1.DataSource = ds;`and see the result. If that doesn't help, comment out this line, too `GridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: @HarutyunImirzyan when I comment out GridView1.DataSource = ds; I get nothing( no error message and no data been dispalyed). When I comment out GridView1.DataBind(); I get this error message: The IListSource does not contain any data sources.

Comment: Ok, You can comment out all the columns in your markup and set AutoGenerateColumns to true. Then remove comments from both aforementioned lines

Comment: @HarutyunImirzyan I just did like you advised and I got the same error: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out

Comment: @HarutyunImirzyan Thank you though for trying to help. I appreciate that.

Comment: Try `GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya no data is been displayed :/

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems in this which i will add ass comments.

```
private void Load_Grid(bool ShouldWeBindToGridView)
{
 //as first whats the point of calling this method and wasting time reading database 
 //the parameter ShouldWeBindToGridView should be used before this whole method.

  DataSet ds = new DataSet();

  //Whenever you can use using USE IT!. it will automatically close connection and dispose.
  using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcnn)){
       conn.Open();
       using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Students", conn)){
         cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)){
           adapter.Fill(ds);
         }
     }
  }

  //if(ds != null) does nothing you just made a new dataset it will be never null. Instead check if it contains any tables and any rows

  if(ds.Tables[0] != null)
    if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0){
      GridView1.DataSource = ds;
      GridView1.DataBind();
    }else{
      GridView1.DataSource = null;
      GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution you have suggested above. No error but no data is been displayed either.

Comment: @ITDeveloper set a break point on sqldatadapter. Do you even get any data in de dataset? nvm after this comment I saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause of the issue. In the backend the stored procedure is a combination of multiple union queries. The number of columns was not the same and I was getting an error in the stored procedure so the dataset was always empty but I do not know why the error was related to multiple data binding when the issue is having empty dataset because of an issue in the stored procedure. I wanted to share the solution in case someone else gets the same issue and it does not come to their mind to check the stored procedure or the backend code.